# Adding a random number before selecting in SQL

Tags: sql, random, gaussian

I am selecting data from an SQL table. So I would do something like:

```
select stellarmass
 from galaxies
 where stellarmass between 3.5 and 5.6
```

My problem is that the table that is currently uploaded does not have scatter imposed on it. So I need to do this myself. Specifically, I need to select random numbers from a gaussian distribution with a specific sigma and add a different random number to each of the stellarmass values, and only then would I like to select it if it still lies between 3.5 and 5.6.

Note: I'm aware it would be simple to query a table of stellarmass values and add scatter to it via Python or something similar, but I need this to be done through SQL. The reason is because these values will act as a pointer to other tables from which I need to extract information.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I assume your `galaxies` dataset does not have some 10^11 entries, so what sort of size table are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using the Millennium Database, so it has millions of entries. I'm cutting it down to only using 0.8% of the full dataset (randomly selected rows)

Comment: Do you need the selection to be repeatable? E.g. if you query it now and then again tomorrow. I am thinking that if you created a table of GalaxyID and numbers with your Gaussian distribution, you can join them and select the required rows.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, to get a random row from a range of rows:

```
select top 1 stellarmass
from galaxies
where stellarmass between 3.5 and 5.6
order by newid()
```

For generating a random number and using it, look into `RAND([seed])` T_SQL function.